# Run one or more .appcache file in a site

Tags: caching, offline

Is it possible to run two appcache file in a site. For example in home.html there is home.appcache while in about.html there is about.appcache , each of the file will cache different resources. I want to know if it's possible to cache by pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already tried it and it is working,it means that there is no need to download all the resources using only one appcache file, we can use one or more appcache file in a site but we need to put it in different html pages. using this technique only the updated resources will be cached and be downloaded,there is no need to download all resources.